# Forecast for group in R with output

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, forecasting

Let me provide any forecast data:

```
df=structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), year = c(1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 
1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L), Jan = c(9007L, 7750L, 
8162L, 7717L, 7792L, 7836L, 9007L, 7750L, 8162L, 7717L, 7792L, 
7836L), Feb = c(8106L, 6981L, 7306L, 7461L, 6957L, 6892L, 8106L, 
6981L, 7306L, 7461L, 6957L, 6892L), Mar = c(8928L, 8038L, 8124L, 
7767L, 7726L, 7791L, 8928L, 8038L, 8124L, 7767L, 7726L, 7791L
), Apr = c(9137L, 8422L, 7870L, 7925L, 8106L, 8192L, 9137L, 8422L, 
7870L, 7925L, 8106L, 8192L), May = c(10017L, 8714L, 9387L, 8623L, 
8890L, 9115L, 10017L, 8714L, 9387L, 8623L, 8890L, 9115L), Jun = c(10826L, 
9512L, 9556L, 8945L, 9299L, 9434L, 10826L, 9512L, 9556L, 8945L, 
9299L, 9434L), Jul = c(11317L, 10120L, 10093L, 10078L, 10625L, 
10484L, 11317L, 10120L, 10093L, 10078L, 10625L, 10484L), Aug = c(10744L, 
9823L, 9620L, 9179L, 9302L, 9827L, 10744L, 9823L, 9620L, 9179L, 
9302L, 9827L), Sep = c(9713L, 8743L, 8285L, 8037L, 8314L, 9110L, 
9713L, 8743L, 8285L, 8037L, 8314L, 9110L), Oct = c(9938L, 9129L, 
8466L, 8488L, 8850L, 9070L, 9938L, 9129L, 8466L, 8488L, 8850L, 
9070L), Nov = c(9161L, 8710L, 8160L, 7874L, 8265L, 8633L, 9161L, 
8710L, 8160L, 7874L, 8265L, 8633L), Dec = c(8927L, 8680L, 8034L, 
8647L, 8796L, 9240L, 8927L, 8680L, 8034L, 8647L, 8796L, 9240L
)), .Names = c("group", "year", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
"Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I want perform forecast for  each group separately(group var is `group`(1 and 2).
I use the `forecast` package and `ets` funtion for automatic selection parameters.

```
library("forecast")
fit <- ets(df,model = "ZZZ")
```

How to do, that forecast was performed for each group?

I.E, I want such output.(For 2 years)

```
   group year        jan jan..95. jan.95.        feb feb..95. feb.95. X. X..1  X X.1 X.2
1      1 1973 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
2      1 1974 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
3      1 1975 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
4      1 1976 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
5      1 1977 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
6      1 1978 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
7      1 1979 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
8      1 1980 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
9      2 1973 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
10     2 1974 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
11     2 1975 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
12     2 1976 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
13     2 1977 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
14     2 1978 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
15     2 1979 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
16     2 1980 pred.value        -       - pred.value        -       - NA   NA NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: You need to `group_by` first and then apply the `ets` model. For example (in base R) you can do something `lapply(split(df, df$group), function(i)ets(i, model = 'ZZZ'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to convert your data into a list of `ts` objects:

```
library(forecast)
ld <- split(df[, -1], df$group)
ld <- lapply(ld, function(x) {ts(c(t(x[,-1])), start = min(x[,1]), frequency = 12)})
```

Next, you can get a list of models.

```
lts <- lapply(ld, ets, model = "ZZZ")
```

And, finally, get the tables with the forecasts:

```
lapply(lts, forecast)
```

Comment: i used your code in many data for two days, and it works good. The biggest thank  you. But is it possible to see the residuals? What model forecasted for 1973 years and what was the  real value?

Comment: Obtaining residuals is easy: `res <- lapply(lts, residuals)`. For your second question you can use the original data set, the models are: `df$group[df$year == 1973]`, and the real values: `df[df$year == 1973,]`. Regards!!

Comment: Juan Antonio Roldán Díaz,I am appologize for worrying you,  i am embarrassing  to ask you , I decided on this data to do another grouping and analyze, but the error occurred. Can I ask you to see what I did wrong. Can you check please what's wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275015/forecat-incorrect-number-of-dimensions-in-r. Thank you