# Forecat : incorrect number of dimensions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, lapply, forecasting

I  conduct TS analysis.
My dput().

```
df=structure(list(month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("Apr", "Aug", "Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "Jul", 
"Jun", "Mar", "May", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
    1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
    1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1981L, 
    1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
    1981L, 1981L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 
    1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
    1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1984L, 
    1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
    1984L, 1984L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
    1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 
    1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1987L, 
    1987L, 1987L, 1987L), cake = structure(c(54L, 33L, 62L, 70L, 
    92L, 97L, 3L, 99L, 80L, 88L, 73L, 83L, 46L, 26L, 53L, 61L, 
    87L, 94L, 2L, 96L, 74L, 82L, 65L, 77L, 38L, 20L, 45L, 52L, 
    81L, 90L, 1L, 93L, 66L, 76L, 56L, 69L, 30L, 15L, 37L, 44L, 
    75L, 85L, 100L, 89L, 57L, 68L, 47L, 60L, 23L, 11L, 29L, 36L, 
    67L, 79L, 98L, 84L, 48L, 59L, 39L, 51L, 18L, 8L, 22L, 28L, 
    58L, 72L, 95L, 78L, 40L, 50L, 31L, 43L, 14L, 6L, 17L, 21L, 
    49L, 64L, 91L, 71L, 32L, 42L, 24L, 35L, 10L, 5L, 13L, 16L, 
    41L, 55L, 86L, 63L, 25L, 34L, 19L, 27L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 12L), .Label = c("10154.696", 
    "10379.224", "10603.752", "5689.504", "5914.032", "6138.560", 
    "6238.622", "6363.087", "6442.272", "6463.150", "6587.615", 
    "6650.772", "6666.799", "6687.677", "6812.142", "6875.300", 
    "6891.327", "6912.205", "6998.555", "7036.670", "7099.828", 
    "7115.855", "7136.733", "7223.083", "7248.663", "7261.198", 
    "7297.533", "7324.355", "7340.382", "7361.260", "7447.610", 
    "7473.191", "7485.725", "7509.326", "7522.060", "7548.883", 
    "7564.910", "7585.788", "7672.138", "7697.719", "7705.501", 
    "7733.854", "7746.588", "7773.411", "7789.438", "7810.315", 
    "7896.666", "7922.246", "7930.029", "7958.381", "7971.115", 
    "7997.938", "8013.965", "8034.843", "8106.171", "8121.193", 
    "8146.774", "8154.557", "8182.909", "8195.643", "8222.466", 
    "8238.493", "8304.060", "8330.699", "8345.721", "8371.301", 
    "8379.084", "8407.436", "8420.171", "8446.994", "8528.588", 
    "8555.227", "8570.249", "8595.829", "8603.612", "8631.964", 
    "8644.698", "8753.116", "8779.754", "8820.357", "8828.140", 
    "8856.492", "8869.226", "8977.643", "9004.282", "9032.058", 
    "9052.667", "9081.019", "9202.171", "9228.809", "9256.586", 
    "9277.195", "9426.698", "9453.337", "9481.114", "9651.226", 
    "9677.865", "9705.641", "9875.754", "9930.169"), class = "factor"), 
    icecream = structure(c(79L, 63L, 81L, 84L, 95L, 97L, 100L, 
    98L, 88L, 91L, 82L, 87L, 62L, 48L, 67L, 72L, 89L, 93L, 99L, 
    94L, 76L, 83L, 70L, 74L, 50L, 33L, 52L, 58L, 78L, 85L, 96L, 
    90L, 65L, 73L, 57L, 64L, 38L, 24L, 41L, 46L, 68L, 75L, 92L, 
    80L, 54L, 61L, 47L, 53L, 28L, 14L, 30L, 36L, 56L, 66L, 86L, 
    71L, 42L, 49L, 37L, 43L, 19L, 9L, 21L, 25L, 45L, 55L, 77L, 
    60L, 31L, 39L, 27L, 32L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 17L, 35L, 44L, 69L, 
    51L, 22L, 29L, 18L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 26L, 34L, 59L, 
    40L, 15L, 20L, 11L, 16L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("3385.834", 
    "3778.830", "3948.779", "4124.808", "4178.019", "4319.547", 
    "4342.230", "4517.359", "4585.426", "4711.662", "4736.627", 
    "4742.014", "4915.965", "5004.123", "5014.631", "5021.709", 
    "5109.700", "5131.026", "5150.224", "5261.328", "5322.590", 
    "5410.013", "5415.633", "5439.154", "5515.562", "5527.707", 
    "5532.057", "5570.050", "5656.213", "5740.192", "5812.339", 
    "5816.038", "5899.870", "5914.260", "5925.189", "5932.101", 
    "5941.954", "6006.774", "6057.884", "6084.031", "6173.592", 
    "6224.003", "6225.088", "6311.199", "6330.308", "6363.928", 
    "6364.167", "6407.747", "6468.652", "6470.314", "6479.920", 
    "6631.617", "6646.099", "6648.738", "6715.593", "6745.815", 
    "6804.502", "6819.387", "6826.069", "6882.919", "6892.105", 
    "6984.050", "7046.898", "7084.607", "7092.952", "7130.098", 
    "7134.058", "7176.124", "7222.477", "7274.188", "7295.503", 
    "7316.767", "7334.341", "7551.164", "7558.942", "7569.422", 
    "7626.165", "7629.133", "7648.558", "7721.562", "7752.579", 
    "7801.250", "7807.326", "7917.988", "8009.607", "8039.695", 
    "8071.334", "8112.267", "8121.785", "8167.836", "8341.913", 
    "8467.124", "8497.833", "8647.995", "8708.185", "8915.546", 
    "9071.327", "9199.960", "9399.616", "9961.726"), class = "factor"), 
    kex = structure(c(37L, 28L, 46L, 55L, 91L, 4L, 21L, 13L, 
    73L, 90L, 66L, 82L, 41L, 32L, 50L, 59L, 100L, 8L, 24L, 16L, 
    78L, 95L, 69L, 85L, 43L, 35L, 53L, 62L, 2L, 10L, 27L, 19L, 
    81L, 97L, 71L, 87L, 45L, 36L, 54L, 63L, 3L, 11L, 26L, 18L, 
    80L, 96L, 70L, 86L, 44L, 34L, 52L, 61L, 1L, 9L, 25L, 17L, 
    77L, 94L, 68L, 84L, 42L, 33L, 51L, 60L, 99L, 7L, 23L, 15L, 
    76L, 92L, 67L, 83L, 40L, 31L, 49L, 58L, 98L, 6L, 22L, 14L, 
    74L, 89L, 65L, 79L, 39L, 30L, 48L, 57L, 93L, 5L, 20L, 12L, 
    72L, 88L, 64L, 75L, 38L, 29L, 47L, 56L), .Label = c("10012.354", 
    "10027.147", "10031.100", "10284.403", "10298.083", "10350.199", 
    "10394.860", "10408.841", "10429.411", "10448.012", "10449.622", 
    "10524.089", "10551.548", "10577.256", "10623.312", "10654.457", 
    "10659.784", "10682.780", "10685.561", "11238.047", "11245.777", 
    "11290.695", "11336.062", "11358.832", "11371.587", "11393.214", 
    "11393.847", "7924.553", "7993.174", "8049.233", "8099.100", 
    "8114.649", "8140.749", "8171.107", "8173.470", "8185.131", 
    "8421.128", "8528.465", "8584.070", "8633.341", "8636.581", 
    "8674.186", "8701.261", "8703.415", "8715.747", "8724.407", 
    "8759.735", "8816.240", "8866.689", "8893.873", "8909.120", 
    "8940.573", "8947.258", "8956.228", "8975.999", "8981.998", 
    "9038.938", "9089.956", "9128.165", "9133.149", "9165.665", 
    "9176.489", "9182.893", "9260.483", "9315.139", "9339.247", 
    "9363.164", "9402.322", "9417.254", "9429.165", "9437.884", 
    "9482.695", "9528.447", "9536.369", "9573.356", "9583.098", 
    "9620.489", "9622.236", "9628.487", "9644.810", "9649.651", 
    "9667.118", "9677.137", "9717.143", "9738.233", "9745.187", 
    "9755.734", "9757.324", "9811.494", "9820.126", "9846.204", 
    "9858.879", "9883.296", "9897.166", "9905.657", "9922.767", 
    "9929.587", "9934.869", "9978.806", "9983.549"), class = "factor"), 
    bread = structure(c(84L, 74L, 85L, 88L, 96L, 97L, 100L, 98L, 
    91L, 92L, 83L, 89L, 68L, 57L, 71L, 75L, 87L, 93L, 99L, 94L, 
    79L, 81L, 72L, 77L, 54L, 41L, 58L, 62L, 78L, 82L, 95L, 86L, 
    66L, 70L, 60L, 64L, 40L, 28L, 46L, 49L, 67L, 73L, 90L, 76L, 
    53L, 59L, 47L, 52L, 29L, 19L, 34L, 38L, 55L, 63L, 80L, 65L, 
    43L, 48L, 36L, 42L, 20L, 11L, 23L, 27L, 44L, 51L, 69L, 56L, 
    32L, 37L, 25L, 31L, 12L, 6L, 15L, 17L, 33L, 39L, 61L, 45L, 
    22L, 26L, 16L, 21L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 24L, 30L, 50L, 35L, 
    14L, 18L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("2166.345", 
    "2648.523", "2736.609", "2898.017", "3085.471", "3140.171", 
    "3219.482", "3379.514", "3539.234", "3566.302", "3644.388", 
    "3712.041", "3816.960", "3832.007", "3870.272", "4023.558", 
    "4056.190", "4071.310", "4165.873", "4217.487", "4300.558", 
    "4317.832", "4373.292", "4374.852", "4518.024", "4556.376", 
    "4558.044", "4712.338", "4740.699", "4753.932", "4794.067", 
    "4814.280", "4863.891", "4893.102", "4908.819", "5026.050", 
    "5051.821", "5076.228", "5242.140", "5289.752", "5298.084", 
    "5300.797", "5325.007", "5364.609", "5395.421", "5437.073", 
    "5552.911", "5561.179", "5617.793", "5658.289", "5741.750", 
    "5825.819", "5855.726", "5879.818", "5881.214", "5892.896", 
    "5955.957", "6018.704", "6089.938", "6107.488", "6145.685", 
    "6195.500", "6256.822", "6377.603", "6405.031", "6416.234", 
    "6420.458", "6546.651", "6644.214", "6647.421", "6668.263", 
    "6706.952", "6793.825", "6814.597", "6837.318", "6937.775", 
    "6972.282", "6994.417", "7026.075", "7157.797", "7251.932", 
    "7364.200", "7394.167", "7444.071", "7495.351", "7501.435", 
    "7629.006", "7637.950", "7648.955", "7692.634", "7737.427", 
    "7950.654", "7992.020", "8116.917", "8259.580", "8406.970", 
    "8750.245", "8842.216", "8881.043", "9621.858"), class = "factor"), 
    pie = structure(c(69L, 67L, 72L, 79L, 6L, 25L, 56L, 39L, 
    95L, 9L, 91L, 2L, 74L, 68L, 81L, 86L, 21L, 41L, 60L, 47L, 
    7L, 19L, 99L, 12L, 80L, 70L, 84L, 93L, 29L, 46L, 61L, 50L, 
    14L, 26L, 4L, 20L, 82L, 71L, 88L, 97L, 35L, 48L, 62L, 54L, 
    17L, 32L, 11L, 23L, 83L, 73L, 92L, 1L, 38L, 49L, 63L, 55L, 
    22L, 36L, 13L, 28L, 85L, 75L, 94L, 3L, 42L, 51L, 64L, 57L, 
    24L, 37L, 15L, 31L, 87L, 76L, 96L, 5L, 44L, 52L, 65L, 58L, 
    27L, 40L, 16L, 33L, 89L, 77L, 98L, 8L, 45L, 53L, 66L, 59L, 
    30L, 43L, 18L, 34L, 90L, 78L, 100L, 10L), .Label = c("10021.538", 
    "10089.497", "10090.666", "10134.899", "10143.466", "10147.420", 
    "10165.583", "10184.298", "10211.385", "10216.074", "10240.421", 
    "10317.115", "10318.226", "10326.369", "10377.197", "10422.607", 
    "10437.822", "10457.876", "10461.052", "10462.739", "10476.329", 
    "10519.485", "10565.467", "10581.157", "10605.485", "10616.507", 
    "10628.549", "10641.434", "10661.863", "10665.320", "10699.108", 
    "10724.935", "10743.562", "10778.105", "10786.766", "10804.639", 
    "10864.942", "10876.955", "10909.292", "10911.331", "10914.655", 
    "10944.505", "10947.342", "10996.167", "11036.150", "11093.419", 
    "11185.536", "11214.739", "11302.686", "11351.962", "11368.703", 
    "11419.258", "11458.410", "11466.567", "11550.255", "11585.645", 
    "11613.335", "11661.755", "11699.302", "11877.405", "12049.813", 
    "12167.703", "12253.485", "12318.013", "12367.487", "12405.828", 
    "8156.854", "8566.438", "8625.615", "8775.256", "8911.947", 
    "8981.635", "9009.357", "9073.980", "9081.786", "9136.948", 
    "9179.541", "9212.663", "9256.038", "9291.757", "9359.667", 
    "9432.769", "9532.766", "9560.171", "9606.922", "9607.613", 
    "9663.313", "9692.747", "9706.817", "9740.635", "9746.330", 
    "9787.663", "9800.377", "9858.417", "9903.287", "9912.382", 
    "9929.028", "9954.085", "9984.490", "9986.527"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("month", 
"year", "cake", "icecream", "kex", "bread", "pie"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

So for 5 positions ( "cake", "icecream", "kex", "bread", "pie"), i want  perform forecast!

```
library(forecast)
ld <- lapply(df, function(x) {ts(c(t(x[,-1])), start = min(x[,1]), frequency = 12)})
lts <- lapply(ld, ets, model = "ZZZ")
lapply(lts, forecast)
```

After it, the error ocurres.

```
 Error in x[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I think  the deal with my data structure, but i can't explane what namely wrong?

How can i understand, why i can't conduct analysis. Maybe i wrong did the grouping?

As final result, i want

```
month   year    cake    icecream    kex    bread
Jan    1988     1226    1019       1149   1220
Feb    1988     1627    1530        1649    1341
```

(it is forecasted value)

Comment: When you do `lapply(df, function(x)`, `x` will be a vector. In the function, you then use `x[,-1]`, suggestion you want to drop the first column (the second dimension). But there is only one dimension! This is why you get an error.

Comment: `lapply(df[-c(1,2)],  function(x){
  myts <- ts(x, start = min(df$year), frequency = 12)
  model <- ets(myts, model = "ZZZ")
  return(forecast(model))
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the continuation of this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187189/forecast-for-group-in-r-with-output/52187591?noredirect=1#comment91497438_52187591)

The code for the analysis is the same, but the structure of the data is different and that is the problem, if you transform the data to have a structure like the previous one, the problem is solved.

```
library(reshape)
df <- cast(melt(df, id=c("month", "year"), na.rm=TRUE), 
           variable + year ~ month)[, c("variable", "year", substring(month.name, 1, 3))]
colnames(df)[1] <- "group"
df[, substring(month.name, 1, 3)] <- lapply(df[, substring(month.name, 1, 3)], 
                                            function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

And now this work:

```
library(forecast)
ld <- split(df[, -1], df$group)
ld <- lapply(ld, function(x) {ts(c(t(x[,-1])), start = min(x[,1]), frequency = 12)})
lts <- lapply(ld, ets, model = "ZZZ")
lf <- lapply(lts, forecast)
lf <- sapply(1:length(lf), 
             function(x) {d <- as.data.frame(lf[[x]])[, 1, drop = F]
                          colnames(d) <- names(lf)[x]
                          d},
             simplify = FALSE)
do.call(cbind, lf)
             cake icecream       kex    bread       pie
May 1987 7480.974 5134.009  9830.727 3903.814 11068.371
Jun 1987 7881.644 5519.485 10254.112 4285.591 11490.782
Jul 1987 8807.531 6429.317 11193.300 5194.330 12436.630
Aug 1987 8079.533 5685.421 10483.109 4451.265 11729.948
Sep 1987 7024.136 4615.184  9446.217 3383.871 10695.142
...
```

Comment: I hesitate to ask you  for help, but I ask you to help, if this is not labor-intensive for you, there are problems with the aggregations in time, so I can not calmly analyze the time series. Tell me how to solve this problem, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313479/aggregation-minutes-time-in-different-time-interval-in-r?noredirect=1#comment91575777_52313479 Sorry for worring you.